# Irrationality of $\sum\limits_{p}{\frac{1}{2^p}}$ over prime p-s

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Just curious about the following problem:

---

*Show that $\sum\limits_{p}{\frac{1}{2^p}}$ where $p$ runs over prime numbers is an irrational number.*

---

It goes under 'Pigeonhole Principle' topic in one of problem set I found on the Web. My idea was to assume $S=\frac{p}{q}$ and show that $q$ can be higher than any $N$. But I can't see any way to implement it.

Comment: Hint: the binary digits (in fact b-ary digits in any base $b$) of any rational number will be ultimately periodic.

Comment: @achille hui  I see your point. A binary fraction for a $\frac{1}{2^p}$ has 1 only in p-th position. Since primary numbers don't have a specific pattern, the occurence of 1-s can't be periodic. But how to formalise this "no specific pattern"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach suggested by achille hui.

Suppose $s =  \sum\limits_{p}{\frac{1}{2^p}}$ is rational, i.e a periodic binary fraction.

Since each $\frac{1}{2^p}$ as a binary fraction has 1 only in $p-th$ position, the sequence of prime numbers must be periodic. In other words, if $n$ is the length of period for $s$ then it should be a prime number $p$ so that $p+nk$ is a prime number for any $k$. But $p+np$ is a composite number.